# Eliminar caracteres de una cadena desde un caracter 'X' hacia la derecha Ruby on Rails

Tags: string, ruby-on-rails, ruby, caracteres

tengo la siguiente variable 'aff' que contiene un numero como se indica abajo:

> aff = 20223844902/50

Esa variable 'aff' puede contener tambien numeros sin tener ninguna '/' como:

> aff = 2033357788

O puede contener diferentes cantidades de numeros luego de la '/' como:

> aff = 20223844902/1
> aff = 20223844902/203

Lo que intento hacer es eliminar a partir de la '/' todos los caracteres que se encuentren a la derecha, en el caso de que exista la barra '/', ya que solo necesito el numero que se encuentra a la izquierda de la barra.
Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `sub` junto con una expresión regular, de tal forma que sustituyas todo lo que venga después de `/` con una cadena vacía; por ejemplo:

```
aff = "20223844902/203"
#=> "20223844902/203"

aff.sub(/\/.*/, "")
#=> "20223844902"
```

Descomponiendo la expresión regular:

- `/` inicia regex.
- `\/` toma el caracter `/`; el caracter `\` anterior es necesario para *escapar* el siguiente caracter, es decir, tomarlo tal como es (de lo contrario se tomaría como *termina regex*).
- `.*` toma todos los caracteres (`*`) sin importar que sea sean (`.`).
- `/` termina regex.

Si quieres un valor numérico, sola agrega `to_i` al final:

```
aff.sub(/\/.*/, "").to_i
#=> 20223844902
```

Nota: es importante considerar que el valor es una cadena de caracteres, no un número, ya que en tu código no tiene `" "` por lo que ruby lo consideraría un número; si ese es el caso, no podrías llevar a cabo la operación que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Gerry, lo solucione utilizando 'split'

Answer (score 0):

Yo suelo usar el método split. Así:

```
aff = "20223844902/203"
#=> "20223844902/203"
aff.split("/")[0]
#=> "20223844902"
```

Crea un arreglo en base al "/" signo de división y muestra el primer elemento, cumpliendo el requisito de la petición.

Comment: Estaria bueno tanto para el OP como para otras personas que vean tu respuesta en un futuro que explicaras que hace tu código.

Answer (score 0):

(\d+)(?=\s*/)
Este regex matchea los números antes de la barra

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación a tus respuestas. Pegar un código solamente no es una respuesta de calidad. Puede resultar obvio para ti pero tal vez no sea tan obvio para otras personas